# Is there a word for receiving a gift?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I receive a thing, I can either steal it, trade for it, or receive it as a gift. Is there a word for "receive as a gift"? As in, "I stole four potatoes, bought six potatoes, and XXX'd three potatoes?"

Comment: In some contexts you might be able to use ***received*** or ***accepted***, but for almost all contexts I think you'll have to go for the two-word ***was given*** (to emphasize the fact of having received the three potatoes as a *gift*, you might also consider ***was gifted***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP also needs to beware of the fact that the verb *receive* or *receiving* has various meanings depending on context. In Britain (and I assume in other English-speaking jurisdictions) there is an offence of *receiving*. It refers to stolen property, where the *receiver* knows it to have been stolen. At the other end of the scale a *Receiver* is someone appointed by a court to take charge of, and manage assets held by a bankrupt.

Answer (score 2):

"I was **gifted** three potatoes". **Gift** works as both a verb and a noun.

A more common use is "I was **given** three potatoes" but this doesn't specifically imply a gift.